# Different nuances of interrogative phrases

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-order, interpretation, interrogatives

> 何{なに}がXですか。
>   Xは何{なん}ですか。

What are the different nuances associated with these two phrases?

Answer (score 4):

Although both sentences could be translated as, *"What is X?"*, a fuller explication reveals the differences.

> 何【なに】　　  が　  X　です　　か。
>     what `[SUBJ]` X `[is]` `[QUESTION]`

Grammatically, the "what" is the subject of this sentence -- the 何【なに】 is the word marked with が, the subject particle.  So we know that this question is about the 何【なに】, and the "X" is a descriptor of that 何【なに】.

Here, we know what X is.  We could be asking what things are X.  For example, if we assume that X = "dog", then we might be asking:

- "What [of the things we see around us] are dogs?"

> X　 が　 　何【なん】  　です　　か。
>     X `[SUBJ]` what  `[is]` `[QUESTION]`

Grammatically, the "X" is the subject of this sentence -- the "X" is the word marked with が, the subject particle.  So we know that this question is about the "X", and the 何【なん】 is a descriptor of that X.

Here, we *don't* know what X is, and we are asking about it.

- "This thing, X, what the heck is it?"

Comment: Ty, I got it. Does the second explanation hold in the case of X**は**何ですか。

Comment: I managed to find a different explanation at [link](https://www.imabi.net/interrogatives.htm), examples 1a and 1b. I'm confused now T-T

Comment: The second explanation seems that for Xは何ですか instead of Xが何ですか (What's the point, when X is whatever?).